# r - Change Variable Column Names in Function

Tags: r, function, assign

Below is a `function` called `change_names` which works, but only on a specific data frame name. In short, I am having issues understanding how to manipulate the `assign` function so it can handle different data frame names.

The `function` basically changes the names on columns of files as I read them in a `for loop`. For example, one file could have a column name `'A'` which should be `'X'` while another file could have the column name `'D'` which should also be named `'X'`.

I have tried a few different outlets to actually change original data frame, `'tempPullList'`, but I need to be able to use the function on a different data frame.

```
#====example different files====
file1 <- data.frame(A = rep(1:10), Y = rep(c("Yellow","Red","Purpule","Green","Blue"), 2),
                    Z = rep(c("Drink", "Food"), 5))

file2 <- data.frame(D = rep(1:10), B = rep(c("Brown","Pink","Purpule","Green","Blue"), 2),
                    Z = rep(c("Drink", "Food"), 5))

file3 <- data.frame(X = rep(1:10), B = rep(c("Brown","Pink","Purpule","Green","Blue"), 2),
                    C = rep(c("Drink", "Food"), 5))

file_list <- list(file1, file2, file3)


#====Package Bank====
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

#====Function====
change_names <- function(x){

  #a list of columns to be renamed
  #through out the files
  chgCols <- c("A",
               "B",
               "C",
               "D")

  #the names the columns will be changed to
  namekey <- c(A = "X",
               B = "Y",
               C = "Z",
               D = "X")

  chgCols <- match(chgCols, colnames(x))               #find any unwanted column indexes in data frame
  chgCols <- colnames(x[, chgCols[!is.na(chgCols)]])   #match indexes to column names w/o NA's

  x <- x %>%                                           #rename associated columns
    plyr::rename(namekey[chgCols])                     #from 'namekey' in dataframe

  assign('tempPullList', x, envir = .GlobalEnv)

}



#====Read in Files====

PullList <- data.frame()
for(file in 1:length(file_list)){
  tempPullList <- data.frame(file_list[file])
  print(file)

  change_names(x = tempPullList)
  PullList <- rbindlist(list(PullList, tempPullList),
                          fill = T)
}
```

Again, right now I am only able to do it when the data frame is called 'tempPullList' I need to be able to do it with another data frame.

i am pretty new to writing functions and especially assigning variables within functions. I would like this function to be as variable as possible. I am currently working on making `chgCols` and `namekey` to be inputs. So any advice on that as well would also be helpful

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between `tempPullList` and `x`? Or provide an example of a typical input and the expected output?

Comment: Following up, I'm having trouble understanding why you wouldn't simply use `return(x)` instead of messing around with namespaces, which is generally not a good idea.

Comment: FYI, you can't have a dataframe that has two columns named "X". To prevent a naming issue r will probably auto rename the second "X" column to "X.1"

Comment: I was wrong...you can make it have the same column name twice...but it will cause problems later. df$X will ignore the second column.

Comment: @AdamSampson i have multiple files i am reading in. one of those could have a column 'A' and the other could have a column 'D' but, they SHOULD both be labeled 'X' as they are both the same thing. In reality, the the column headers of each file are all over the place. Think, 'ID', 'ItemID', Item.Id, ItemId, etc. i want them all to be 'ItemId'. I inter changed 'ItemId' to 'X' for simplicity.

Comment: @Zach i have created an example with input and desired output. but i need to be able to do it with different data frames -- not 'tempPullList'. Also, can you explain what you mean by use the `return` function if it is still relevant?

Comment: Gotcha. If different files have different column names that makes more sense.

Comment: BTW: having a function `assign` a value to the global environment is **"A Bad Thing (tm)"**. It *might* work for you for a while. It will almost always cause problems if others have to use it unless you take great pains in documenting and working around things. The `quantmod` package does this, and many questions on SO are a direct result of (or are directly complicated by) this behavior. Please press the `I Believe` button on this one.

Comment: @r2evans what would be a better method?

Comment: i am pretty new to writing functions and especially assigning variables within functions. I would like this function to be as variable as possible. I am currently working on making `chgCols` and `namekey` to be inputs. So any advice on that as well would also be helpful.

Comment: In general, I think the overarching opinion (among those who are "adept" at programming) is that ["function programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) is more intuitive, much easier to troubleshoot/maintain, and by avoiding ["side-effect"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/40297/147602), so many other things "Just Work (tm)". There are packages that offer side-effect (e.g., `quantmod`), there are good functions that *must* work in side-effect (`write.csv`). The premise is: give the func everything it needs, explicitly.

Comment: @r2evans how can explicitly tell the function, in this specific case, to handle any dataframe and not just a dataframe named 'tempPullList'? i do this multiple times in a code i am developing. A few times for a dataframe called 'tempPullList' and then it is needed on a two other data frames.

Comment: If you have a function, provide all of it in your question, not just some code from inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Example data:

```
column_name_lookup <- data.frame(orig = c("a","b","c","d"),
                                 new = c("X","Y","z","X"),
                                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

test_df <- data.frame(a = 1:5,
                      c = 2:6,
                      b = 3:7,
                      e = 4:8,
                      d = 5:9)
```

> ```
>   a c b e d
> 1 1 2 3 4 5
> 2 2 3 4 5 6
> 3 3 4 5 6 7
> 4 4 5 6 7 8
> 5 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

Code to change names:

```
new_names <- column_name_lookup$new[match(names(test_df),column_name_lookup$orig)]

names(test_df) <- ifelse(is.na(new_names),names(test_df),new_names)
```

> ```
>   X z Y e X
> 1 1 2 3 4 5
> 2 2 3 4 5 6
> 3 3 4 5 6 7
> 4 4 5 6 7 8
> 5 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

Comment: Please see my edit's with a more reproducible example.